# Thread BLOCKED on InetAddress.getByName 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, kubernetes, prometheus, netty, zio-http

I'm facing a situation where my application hangs at startup because of a "deadlock" situation related to `InetAddress.getByName` but it's not clear to me what would be the way to fix it.

To give some context, the 2 threads involved are not directly in my control:

- 1 thread (BLOCKED) is starting a Prometheus HTTP server
- 1 thread (RUNNABLE) is ZIO Http client library related, calling some Netty stuff as a client (not server)

The relevant code of the 1st thread is:

```java
new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", somePort)
```

And the second:

```java
static final InetAddress INET6_ANY = InetAddress.getByName("::")
static final InetAddress INET_ANY = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0")
```

I've read that using `InetAddress` may involve some blocking etc.. but why would it hangs forever? Especially as we're referring to the local address `0.0.0.0` and not some remote address.

This app is running in a container in Kubernetes if this could explain something.

```bash
$ cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.42.126.184   my-app-756f44d67-tgr5b
```

*Note that this is not always reproducible but we've seen several occurrences lately.*

**Could this be a "bug" as in somehow a misusage of the libraries? Or am I maybe missing something that must be defined for such code to work in a Kubernetes context?**

---

For completeness, here is the thread dump for these 2 threads.

The one BLOCKED:

```
"ZScheduler-Worker-6" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=276.23ms elapsed=7541.20s tid=0x00007f7bd54d4880 nid=0x55 waiting for monitor entry  [0x00007f7b663f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000a02e9a90> (a java.util.HashSet)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BootLoader.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.<clinit>(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.httpserver.HTTPServer$Builder.makeInetSocketAddress(HTTPServer.java:209)
    at io.prometheus.metrics.exporter.httpserver.HTTPServer$Builder.buildAndStart(HTTPServer.java:197)
    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus.PrometheusHttpServer.<init>(PrometheusHttpServer.java:71)
    at io.opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus.PrometheusHttpServerBuilder.build(PrometheusHttpServerBuilder.java:68)
    at com.myapp.metrics.sdk.PrometheusMetricReader$.$anonfun$startReader$2(PrometheusMetricReader.scala:21)
    at com.myapp.metrics.sdk.PrometheusMetricReader$$$Lambda$1109/0x00007f7b7840e078.apply(Unknown Source)
    at zio.ZIOCompanionVersionSpecific.$anonfun$attempt$1(ZIOCompanionVersionSpecific.scala:100)
    at zio.ZIOCompanionVersionSpecific$$Lambda$430/0x00007f7b782ba000.apply(Unknown Source)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:904)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateEffect(FiberRuntime.scala:381)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateMessageWhileSuspended(FiberRuntime.scala:504)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.drainQueueOnCurrentThread(FiberRuntime.scala:220)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.run(FiberRuntime.scala:139)
    at zio.internal.ZScheduler$$anon$4.run(ZScheduler.scala:478)
```

The one "locking":

```
"ZScheduler-Worker-20" #44 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=191.27ms elapsed=7541.20s tid=0x00007f7bd54e2e70 nid=0x63 in Object.wait()  [0x00007f7b655e3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.unsafeInetAddrByName(LinuxSocket.java:364)
    - waiting on the Class initialization monitor for java.net.InetAddress
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.<clinit>(LinuxSocket.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(java.base@17.0.10/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000a02e9a90> (a java.util.HashSet)
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:36)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@17.0.10/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:430)
    at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@17.0.10/Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:422)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:388)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:218)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:40)
    at zio.http.netty.ChannelFactories$Client$.$anonfun$fromConfig$4(ChannelFactories.scala:83)
    at zio.http.netty.ChannelFactories$Client$$$Lambda$966/0x00007f7b783d3e60.apply(Unknown Source)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:890)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:1024)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.runLoop(FiberRuntime.scala:967)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateEffect(FiberRuntime.scala:381)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.evaluateMessageWhileSuspended(FiberRuntime.scala:504)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.drainQueueOnCurrentThread(FiberRuntime.scala:220)
    at zio.internal.FiberRuntime.run(FiberRuntime.scala:139)
    at zio.internal.ZScheduler$$anon$4.run(ZScheduler.scala:478)
```

Comment: Are they binding different ports? Perhaps one server is blocked waiting for the other server to release the address bind.

Comment: @Rogue 1 thread (Prometheus) is expecting to bind to a (fixed) port but the other one is not supposed to AFAIK, it's just some client code to call other HTTP services.

Comment: So you're almost always going to be binding to a port (unless you're doing some layer <3 stuff), and for HTTP that's usually port 80. If you haven't configured these two services to use different ports, then that would be the first thing I would adjust.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear but only one thread is a server (for which I control the port it binds to). The other one is just some client code AFAIK but I may be missing something.

Comment: Aha no, that'd be my own oversight of "client". The first thread is `BLOCKED` inside of the static initializer of `InetAddress`, so any thread that attempts to use `InetAddress` will also become "blocked". You'll really need to solve the first thread being `BLOCKED` on that `#loadLibrary` call.

Comment: Yeah that actually looks like a deadlock. You could try to solve this by using `InetAddress` at the start of your application (before the other code runs - especially before using anything from Netty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

This [has been fixed in the Netty repository](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/13879) and will be included in Netty `4.1.108.Final`.

## What happens

From your thread dumps, I can see the following:

- In the blocked thread, the class initializer of `InetAddress` waits for a native library to be loaded but it cannot because another thread is loading a native library.
- The other thread attempts to use `InetAddress` as part of loading a native library. Specifically, the class initializer of Netty's `Native` class [loads a native library](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/f78f55f69716e022e328aeb77340574d7cc9b9d3/transport-classes-epoll/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/epoll/Native.java#L85) ([`netty_transport_native_epoll`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/f78f55f69716e022e328aeb77340574d7cc9b9d3/transport-classes-epoll/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/epoll/Native.java#L319C33-L319C61)) which in turn makes an upcall to `LinuxSocket` (or at least initializes it) which requires `InetAddress` to be loaded.

So the problem is that Netty uses `InetAddress` while loading a native library which can occur during initialization.

## A workaround

You can make sure that `InetAddress` is fully initialized before giving Netty a chance to do anything. You can do that by running `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` at the beginning of your main. That should be before Netty is used anywhere and it should initialize `InetAddress`

## Actually solving the problem

You can file a bugreport to the Netty team (or even write a pull request yourself).

One solution they could implement is to initialize `InetAddress` themselves before loading native libraries (that rely on it being loaded/loadable).

For example, they could add a `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` call into the `Native` class before actually loading stuff (e.g. at the beginning of `Native.loadNativeLibrary`).

Alternatively, it might even possible to change something that *loading* the native library doesn't require `InetAddress` at all. However, I don't have sufficient knowledge about Netty (internals) to be able to judge that.

Comment: Thanks! Will probably go with a workaround for now. For the record, I opened an issue on Netty: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/13871.

Comment: Bug fixed by Netty: https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/13879 

Comment: That's good to hear.